# Ohmic power loss due to electric field

Tags: power, electromagnetic, microwave, loss, conductors

Recently I read in the basic EM theory course , that the Ohmic power dissipated in a conductor is directly proportional to the conductivity and the square of the electric field intensity , but we know perfect conductors (conductivity=inf) dissipate zero power , isn't this contradictory , also formula is given on Page 391 , Alexander Sadiku ,EM Theory , thanks.

Comment: Didn't you think that including the formula you're asking about in your question would make sense?

Answer (score 3):

A Perfect conductor has zero (steady state) electric field across it by definition, otherwise infinite current would flow.

The statement above is just P=V^2/R generalised to a unknown conductor geometry and written in terms of conductivity and field strength rather then resistance and applied terminal voltage.